# How to clarify a question closed as site specific

Tags: discussion, meta, closed-questions, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question [How to handle an unnecessarily complex question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376416/167867) was closed as site specific. I didn't intend it as such, as any Stack Exchange site can have the kind of overly complex question the meta question asks about. Well, maybe not Code Golf - but most any site. :-)

The close notice says, "If this question does relate to multiple sites in our network, please edit it to clarify why." That seems difficult to do in a satisfying way. It's like clarifying why gravity isn't specific to just my house. I can say, well, for example, my neighbor's house is also affected because it's also made of matter and also sitting on a giant sphere of matter. It's similar for which sites that can have questions with extraneous details that impede understanding. I can say, well, for example, Cooking Stack Exchange could also have an overly complex question, such as one about pumpkin spice lattes that includes unrelated details of preparing duck. However, it doesn't seem like much of a clarification.

The question of how to clarify what makes the question site general begs the question of what purportedly makes the question site specific. While there were lots of comments and SO, which is where the question's example was from, there were no comments explaining the reason for closure, that the question was specific to SO (or some other site).

What about the question is site specific? Or if unknown, how would I go about finding out?

Comment: That's odd, it certainly applies to [worldbuilding.se] and [skeptics.se] from time to time where many questions include unnecessary "fluff" which we generally comment to ask the OP to remove. Perhaps if you'd included examples from other sites than the one you did in that Q, others may have appreciated the broad applicability.

Comment: I don't think it's site-specific, I do agree with [the last comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376416/how-to-handle-an-unnecessarily-complex-question#comment1254797_376416), but it lacks multiple good (excellent) examples. Closed seeking details would have been a better reason. --- Great examples could be searched for, on sites of completely different subjects, and those examples offered; demonstrating both that the occurrence is frequent enough and occurs in all walks of life. --- Lack of research is another possible close reason, the single example was weak; as was mentioned.

Comment: Do all sites deal with this issue in the same way? Do some sites have policies that we could recommend universally? Do some sites deal with this in a way that's more problematical? So in general you'd need to do significant multi site research and edit that into the question I think.