# Must a meta SE question prove site generality?

Tags: discussion, meta, closed-questions, scope

My question [How to handle an unnecessarily complex question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376416/167867) was closed as site specific. Although no one explained why in principle any site couldn't have a "noisy" question, there were comments about the question not citing examples from multiple sites (also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376446/167867)).

Is the "price of admission" to ask a question on meta SE that you have to know of or go looking for examples from multiple sites? What if you've encountered an example on one site, which raises a question you expect also applies elsewhere? Do you have find evidence to prove it? Or is it OK to ask abstractly? Or does it depend?

Answer (score 12):

There's a certain level of structural conformity that all sites have. You can only have at most one accepted answer per question for instance. There are differences however, due to scale and culture.

Here's one comparison of Stack Overflow with one other site...

- Stack Overflow has 24 moderators and 6000 questions per day.
- [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/)  has 3 moderators and 9 questions per day.

On Stack Overflow the close vote queue currently contains over 5000 questions. The likelihood there is that if your question is too broad it will be closed and you're not that likely to get any additional comments as to why that is so as the people trying to drink from the firehose of the close vote queue move onto the next question that might need closing.

On Personal Finance & Money there are currently 2 questions in the close vote queue. The likelihood that someone will try to provide individual help for something too broad such that it might become on-topic is higher because life is slower there.

So the chance that a moderator or even another experienced user might be able to spend time individually helping someone on Money is greater than on Stack Overflow just by that scale difference.

All that amounts to a difference in how sites operate together with the difference that is how the team of moderators decide they wish to operate that's probably partly down to scale too. Moderators on Stack Overflow almost certainly deal with rants, rage quits and other issues that other sites may only get very occasionally.

The other thing is what do you want to achieve with your question? Do you want us to create some "you must operate like this" rule when faced with a complex question from our ivory Meta tower that all sites must cleave to? How would we enforce that?

You've started from the most unique and unusual site in terms of volume and you're wanting to have a general discussion that may not even apply to any other site. That's what your question needs to establish in order to ask it here rather than on Stack Overflow's Meta.

Comment: An altered version of your last question: "Is it even possible to have this issue on other sites?" The example question referenced here may be about over-complex questions, but the specific reasons why it is viewed as overcomplex relates to programming languages explicitly which automatically makes it irrelevant to a huge portion of our sites. At the point a question has to be so over-generalized as to make it relevant to other sites on the network, it's probably not a discussion worth having anymore.

Answer (score 12):

I think Robert Longson's answer addresses it pretty well but, as someone who's spent a lot of time on meta sites across the network and who recognizes how different various sites are, I want to emphasize that getting the MSE answer to a question about some site policy questions isn't always useful.

Each of our sites has a unique culture and will make slightly different decisions about how to use the platform. While there are some overarching rules that we feel are important to follow everywhere, there are far fewer than you might imagine. That's why each site has their own meta.

Some examples:

- **Identification questions** - On some sites, they're outright banned, other sites allow them for any reason, other sites set requirements that must be followed or else the question is closed. There's no single policy about these.
- **Subjective questions** - While purely subjective questions are generally out of scope because we make an effort to focus on objective questions or subjective questions that can be backed up with sources... the degree to which subjectivity is allowed varies between sites.
- **Research effort** - Some sites require significantly more research to be shown in the question than others.
- **Shopping questions** - While these are generally off topic on most of our sites, we specifically have two sites that (with very strict rules) are pretty much just for product recommendations.

So, the thing you need to ask yourself when you're choosing where to ask a policy question is "*Is this something that might be niche to a specific site's policy or is this something I think might be established globally?*" And, in many cases, for *policy* the answer will be - it's local to the site, so should be asked on the child meta.

The thing is, many users across the network aren't even aware of MSE and so trying to use MSE to set policy expectations network wide isn't going to meet with great success... Heck, many site users aren't even aware of their site's child meta but the moderators and curators of the site generally are.

So if you want to understand how a specific site works or request a change to a specific site's policy... you're better off asking the experts on that site rather than asking here... and even if the end result is that they link you to a resource here or in the help center, that's OK! Child metas are valid places to get information about network-wide policy, too!

---

I understand the close reason might be causing some confusion, too... "only relates to one site" is kinda used in two cases - it really only relates to a single site **or** it's something that is decided at the per-site level, and thus, should be asked on any site that wishes to take up that discussion.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to prove that your question applies to multiple sites. However, for it to be asked here then it should.

If it’s not obvious from your question that it applies to more than one site then users will vote to close it as site specific. If you want to re-open that question then you will need to make its applicability to more than one site more obvious and including links to Q&As from more than one site is one way to do that.